# Passing a PHP variable via ?page= within a single page web app

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a single page Webapp using Bootstrap 3.  It looks and feels like the standard IOS contacts app.  I am using it for personal data on contacts.  The contacts are in a sql table which I am querying.  I am trying to pass a the PHP mySql id result to an internal #details id element.

The link is:

```
<a href="#details?page=<?php echo $duty_row['id'];?>">name</a>
```

The div is:

```
<article id="details">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <?php 
            $therecord = $_GET['page'];
            $result = $Con ->query("SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `id` = '$therecord'");
            $details_row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
        ?>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="#on_duty"><div class="col-xs-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left floatleft apple_back_chevron appleBlue" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6"><p class="apple_back_text appleBlue">On Duty Coordinators</p></div></a>
                <a href="#edit_coordinators?page=<?php echo $details_row['id'] ;?>"><div class="col-xs-4"><p class="apple_forward_text appleBlue floatright">Edit</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right floatright apple_forward_chevron appleBlue" aria-hidden="true"></p></div></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-circle" src="" alt="photo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <h2><?php echo $details_row['name'];?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>          
            <div class="row">
                <div class="apple_list appleGray">
                     <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <p class="appleBlue">station</p>
                        <p class="appleDGray"><?php echo $details_row['station']; ?></p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-xs-4">
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="row">
              <div class="apple_list appleGray">
                     <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <p class="appleBlue">mobile</p>
                        <p class="appleDGray"><?php echo $details_row['mobile']; ?></p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-xs-2"> <a href="sms:<?php echo $details_row['mobile']; ?>"><img class="img-responsive apple_Glyph" src="_images/sms.png"></a></div>
                     <div class="col-xs-2"> <a href="tel:<?php echo $details_row['mobile']; ?>"><img class="img-responsive apple_Glyph" src="_images/phone.png"></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /container -->
    </article>
```

How do I pass a PHP "?page=$recordNo" internally?  The page id is being passed, but not getting picked up by the next PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<a href="?page=<?php echo $duty_row['id'];?>#details">name</a>
```

It is also very possible you could write it like so:

```
<a href="?page=<?=$duty_row['id']?>#details">name</a>
```

Basically, `?` starts the query string and (if included) is always before the page anchor (fragment) `#` in a URI. See [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) for more info.

Comment: This partially works, but sends me out to safari and screws up the html and css.  Something to work with, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
<a href="#details?page=<?php echo $duty_row['id'];?>">name</a>
```

Because there's an "hashtag", so it's interpreted by the browser as an in-page navigation, and the request isn't sent to the server, unless you catch it with javascript and then perform some ajax request...

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems completely unrelated to PHP or MySQL.

Just look at the generated mark-up, which will look like this (re-indented to improve readability):

```
<a href="#edit_coordinators?page=333">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <p class="apple_forward_text appleBlue floatright">Edit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right floatright apple_forward_chevron appleBlue" aria-hidden="true"></p>
     </div>
</a>
```

There're two obvious issues:

- The `<a>` tag is an inline element. It cannot have a whole bunch of block elements inside.
- You inject the `page` GET parameter in the hash part of the URL, which is client-side only and is never sent to the server. It should be `?page=333#edit_coordinators`

Said that, I admit I can't fully understand what you have in mind but it you really have a single-page application it has to be coded in JavaScript and possibly use AJAX. With just server-side technologies you can only 
build a conventional web application.